# convertir una imagen guardada en byte en una imagen itextsharp para mostrar en PDF C#

Tags: c#, sql, itextsharp

Necesito convertir una imagen guardada en byte en la base de datos (SQL) para poder imprimirla a un pdf con itextsharp

En este codigo llamo al metodo donde se consulta el byte de la base de datos.

```
string imgByte = obtenerByteImagen (codigo, codigoCuentas, imageByte, cone);
            Byte[] img = Convert.FromBase64String(imgByte);
```

Este es el metodo:

```
public string obtenerByteImagen(string codigo, string codigoCuentas, string imageByte, SqlConnection cone) {

    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        cone.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cone;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT codigoCuentas FROM dbo.pruebasMil where identificador = '" + codigo + "'";
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //reader.Read();

        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;



        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["nombre"]));

            codigoCuentas = reader["codigoCuentas"].ToString();

            cone.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    try
    {
        cone.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cone;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT logo FROM dbo.cuentas where codigo = '" + codigoCuentas + "'";
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //reader.Read();

        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;



        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["nombre"]));

            imageByte = reader["logo"].ToString();

            cone.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return imageByte;
}
```

Aqui lo convierto a imagen de itextsharp y lo pongo en el documento:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image12 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img);
document.Add(image12);
```

El error que me da es el siguente:

> System.FormatException: 'La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 válida porque contiene un carácter que no es Base 64, más de dos caracteres de relleno o un carácter no válido entre los caracteres de relleno. '

En esta linea de codigo:

```
Byte[] img = Convert.FromBase64String(imgByte);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No es aconsejable llevar las imágenes o archivos a la base de datos pues 
   implica mucho espacio de almacenamiento a usar, lo cual
   te puede traer problemas pues tu base de datos crecería demasiado(es
   mi opnion)
2. Para poder usar una imagen en iTextSharp podrías usar esta pedazo de código.
   Como podras ver convertimos primero el byte[] a una imagen para luego usarla 
   en el reporte.

   ```
   public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
   {
       // Convierte tu string 64 a un byte[]
       var imagenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
       var ms = new MemoryStream(imagenBytes, 0,
           imagenBytes.Length);

       // Convierte tu byte[] a imagen 
       ms.Write(imagenBytes, 0, imagenBytes.Length);
       var image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
       return image;
   }
   ```

   Uso:

   ```
   iTextSharp.text.Image image12 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(
                      Base64ToImage(
                          obtenerByteImagen (codigo, codigoCuentas, imageByte, cone)
                      ),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   ```

saludos espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Hola, estaba probando el codigo pero me aparece el siguiente error
" Error CS0104 'Image' es una referencia ambigua entre 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' y 'iTextSharp.text.Image"
" 
Este se muestra en el metodo que me pusiste como solucion, que podra ser?

Comment: claro eso pasa cuando dos namespaces tiene los mismos nombres, solo tienes que poner el namespace completo por ejemplo System.Drawing.Image.

Answer (score 0):

supongo que no publicare esto pues no estoy logeao, pero, aunque no soy de la idea de usar imágenes en las beses de datos, sea donde fuere tendrán que estar, y con todo esto del "Gran dato", pues no se, hablar del peso de imágenes debería de ser de la era del cromañon. ¡Qué no te quito razón!, pero almacenes de datos son la era.

Comment: Por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos